# graphQL slow response and duplicate response

Tags: mongodb, meteor, graphql, apollo, mantrajs

Does anyone have experienced about slow response from using graphQL ?

This is my code in resolver:

```
getActiveCaseWithActiveProcess(){
    console.log ("getActiveCaseWithActiveProcess");

    var result = [];
    var activeElements = ActiveElements.find({
        type:"signal",
        $or:[
         {signalRef:"start-process"},
         {signalRef:"start-task"},
         {signalRef:"close-case"}
        ]
    },{limit:200}).fetch();

    for (var AE of activeElements){

      var checkAECount = ActiveElements.find({caseId:AE['caseId']}).count();
      if (checkAECount <= 3){
        console.log ('caseId: ' +  AE['caseId']);
        var checkExistInResult = result.filter(function (obj) {
            return obj.caseId === AE['caseId'];
        })[0];

        if (checkExistInResult == null){
          result.push({
            caseId: AE['caseId'],
            caseStart: AE['createdDate']
          });
        }
      }
    }
    console.log("loaded successfully");
    return result;
}
```

I have a huge data from my collection actually. Approximately 20000 records. However when I load this, the response is too slow and it can repeat to reload by itself which makes the response is even longer.

```
I20160812-04:07:25.968(0)? caseId: CASE-0000000284, 
I20160812-04:07:26.890(0)? caseId: CASE-0000000285
I20160812-04:07:28.200(0)? caseId: CASE-0000000285
I20160812-04:07:28.214(0)? getActiveCaseWithActiveProcess
I20160812-04:07:28.219(0)? caseId: CASE-0000000194
I20160812-04:07:29.261(0)? caseId: CASE-0000000197
```

As you notice from my attachment above, at this time(20160812-04:07:28.214) the server repeats to load from the beginning again, and that's why the response will take longer.

This is not always happening. It happens when the server loads slowly. When the server loads fast. Everything just runs smoothly.

Comment: I'm curious to know: instead of loading all records on the fly, why don't you use `connection` type for this and make DB queries using `connection`'s cursor?

Answer (score 1):

Not really enough information to answer that question here, but my guess would be that it has nothing to do with GraphQL. I think your client just cancels the request and makes another one because the first one timed out. You can find out if that happens by logging requests to your server before they're passed to GraphQL.